# How do I get the next button to be disabled until an option is selected?

Tags: jquery, contact-form-7

I have the following code. The next button is currently disabled, however, I want the next button to not be disabled when an option from my select input is chosen (not including the first option which is disabled).

```
  $(document).ready( function(){
var $option = $("option:contains('Please select an option')");
var $btnNext2 = $('button.cf7mls_next');
$option.attr('disabled',true);
$btnNext2.attr('disabled',true);
});
```

I am assuming there will need to be an if statement involved somewhere, however, I am working with contact form 7 on WordPress so it may be slightly different.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Listen for the `select` `change` event then remove the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you need to attach a `change` event handler to the `select` which detects what the selected `value` is, and then enables/disables the button based on that value:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $btn = $('.cf7mls_next');

  $('select').on('change', e => {
    $btn.prop('disabled', e.target.value == '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">Please select an option</option>
  <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="Fizz">Fizz</option>
  <option value="Buzz">Buzz</option>
</select>

<button class="cf7mls_next" disabled>Next</button>
```

Comment: That's great thank you. Do you have any idea what I can do if I have multiple select options (all of which need to change before button is no longer disabled)

Comment: In that case you would need to loop through all your select elements and check them individually.

Comment: By "loop" there are looping functions such as .filter() and the misnamed ".some()", so it doesn't have to be a `for` loop.